# Weird behavior of push_back() a filesystem::path's .string().data() result into a "vector<const char *>"

Tags: c++, string, vector, char, std-filesystem

Running this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = filesystem;

int main() {
    vector<fs::path> paths{"a.o", "b.o"};

    vector<const char *> argv{};
    for (auto &p : paths) {
        argv.push_back(p.string().data()); // line A
    }
    argv.push_back(paths[0].string().data());
    argv.push_back(paths[1].string().data());

    for (auto &s : argv) {
        cout << s << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

gets

```
b.o
b.o
a.o
b.o
```

Why isn't the first element of argv "a.o"?

I try to break at line A, finding out that when "b.o" is push_back() into argv, the first element of argv *changed* from "a.o" to "b.o".

Then, when I change line A to

```
        argv.push_back(p.string().c_str()); // line A: .string().data() -> .string().c_str()
```

Same results.

When I change line A to

```
        argv.push_back(p.c_str()); // line A: .string().data() -> .c_str()
```

Suddenly I get what expected:

```
a.o
b.o
a.o
b.o
```

Can someone explain the weird behavior and the difference between .string().data() and .c_str()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that [the `path::string()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) returns the string *by value*.

A value which will be *destructed* as soon as the expression `p.string().data()` ends.

That means the pointer will become immediately invalid and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you try to dereference it (for example when printing it).

The obvious solution is to not use vectors of `char*` for strings, but vector of `std::string` instead.

---

As for the difference between using `p.string().data()` (or `p.string().c_str()`) and `p.c_str()`, it's that `p.c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal string inside the `path` object referenced by `p`. That `path` object will not be destructed until you either `clear` the vector or the life-time of the vector (and its contained object) ends (when the vector is destructed).

Note that if you used a loop such as

```
for (auto p : paths) { ... }
```

where `p` is a copy of the `path` objects, then you would have the same problem even with `p.c_str()`, as then the object `p` would end its life and be destructed at the end of each iteration of the loop.